# Determine the continuity and differentiability of a case-defined function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x^2-3x+1& \text{x<1}\\
(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}& \text{x $\geqslant$ 1}
\end{cases}$$

a. Show that $f$ is continuous at $1$. 
b. Find $f '(1)$ from the right and $f '(x)$ from the left, if they exist. This is the same as $\displaystyle\lim_{x->1^+} f '(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x->1^-} f '(x)$, respectively.
c. Is $f$ differentiable at $1$? If not, identify whether the graph of $f$ has a corner, a cusp, or a vertical tangent line at $x = 1$.

---

So far, I have only been able to answer b). I'm also not sure if it's correct. I simply just tested the right and left limit of $x\to 1$ of both $f '(x)$. Found  $$\lim_{x\to 1}2x^2-3x+1  = 1$$ and  $$\lim_{x\to1} \frac32(x-1)^{1/2} = DNE$$

Comment: So far, I have only been able to answer b). I'm also not sure if its correct. I simply just tested the right and left limit of x-> 1 of both f '(x) . Limit of x->1 of 2x^2-3x+1 = 1 and the limit of x->1 3/2(x-1)^1/2 = dne .

Comment: You should put your attempts and thoughts into your post as an edit. In general, for the future, people will not question you quite so much if you write what you have done already. Otherwise it just looks like someone is asking us to do their homework for them. Welcome Welcome.

Comment: @J.W Perry. If I was really wanted someone to do my homework for me. I would have posted about 30+ questions haha. Just asking for help and advice on the problem. Thats all

Comment: :)). I know your good intentions. As an aside, there are actually limits to how many questions you can post over time.

Comment: Definitely, I understand where you're coming from. I usually help out at a C++ forum. I didn't want to continue writing nonsense, since I did not know how to format the math text. I wanted everyone to first understand the question. Thanks for editing it by the way.

Answer (score 0):

$a)$ For a function $f$ to be continuous at a point, we have that:

$1.$ $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists

$2.$ The value $f(x)$  at $a$ exists

$3.$ $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$

Using these three conditions, just sub in for $x=1$.

$b)$ Differentiate $f(x)$ and find the left-hand limit and right-hand limit at $x=1$: Use the fact that $f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
6x-3& \text{x<1}\\
\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}& \text{x $\geqslant$ 1}
\end{cases}$

$c)$ Based off $b)$, what do you get?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback a) 

I did exactly what you said but for me it seemed pretty sketchy. Both functions = 0 but I'm not sure how this even proves it is continuous at 1.

Comment: Well, that's the definition of being continuous at a point! As long as you show that the limits exist at $x = 1$, the value exists $x = 1$ and the limit at $x = 1$ equals the value at $x = 1$, you should be fine for that. :P

Comment: Hm, Alright. I would assume I would have to do much more than that haha. b) I posted above that I did do B) and I noticed the first function if x < 1. I noticed that it does exist when it approaches 1 but the second function x > 1. Does not exist when it is approaching 1 from the left. Based off that information, I assume it is a vertical Tangent. Because it can't be a cusp/corner. Or am I horribly wrong? This is my weakest subject on this chapter >.<

Answer (score 0):

For continuous we check left and right limit on $x=1$.
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}(2x^2-3x+1)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}((x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}})=0$$
Left and right limit at $x=1$ are equal so we prove that our function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$. 

 For derivative we have simmilar idea. We have to check left and right derivative at $x=2$ if left and right derivartive are eqaul our function is derivative at $x=2$.

Definiton of derivative :$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}(\frac{2x^2-3x+1-0}{x-1}=\frac{2x-3}{1})=-1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}(\frac{(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}-0}{x-1}=\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^\frac{1}{2}=0)$$
So our function is not derivabile at $x=1$.